# React / Enzyme testing value of HTML Label?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I want to test that my label component is properly parsing the data in the principal object.

This is my label:

```
<label id="userInfo"><b>Logged in as: </b>{principal.emailAddress}, <b>Role: </b>{userRole}</label>
```

And this is my test, which is not currently working:

```
describe("Testing User Info displaying correctly", () =>{
  it("when provided principal data, it should correctly combine the username and role", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('[data-test-id="userInfo"]').text()).to.equal("Logged in as: jdoe@foo.bar, Role: Subscriber");
    });
});
```

How can I check that the value of my label, or more accurately the text between the tags, is being shown correctly?

Currently the test fails with the following message:

```
"Method “text” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead."
```

Comment: What's wrong with current  code? I think its correctly checking

Comment: Post edited to show test failed message

Answer (score 1):

with this [reference](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/equals.html), expect statement should be like below:

```
expect(wrapper.find('[data-test-id="userInfo"]').text().equals("Logged in as: jdoe@foo.bar, Role: Subscriber")).to.equal(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still fails with the same message.

Comment: `wrapper.find()` returns an array of the results. I guess you should try `wrapper.find('[data-test-id="userInfo"]')[0].text()`

Comment: I get  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined" when trying that

Comment: try with `wrapper.find('label#userInfo')` or `wrapper.find('#userInfo')`.

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined``` on both of those :/